# An unexpected error occurred during response processing (Name: ECN) WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I'm developing an app on WP7 and decided to add a Microsoft Advertisement to my application.

I added the control and setup the width/height, inserted my app id and ad unit id and published it to my phone. However I keep getting the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred during response processing (Name: ECN)

I don't receive this error when use I "test_client" for app id and "Image300_50" for ad unit id.

Does anyone have any clues as to what the reason for this error may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this official statement from Microsoft about that error, and it appears to be that there aren't any ads to match your app.

> This error is only visible to app developers that are debugging the
>   use of the Microsoft Ad Control in a development environment.  As of
>   February 24, 2011, this scenario will now return the error “No ad
>   available”.  In production the ad control would simply not display an
>   ad if there is an error or if there is no ad to display.  There is no
>   user facing impact.  Please reference the Monetization Best Practices
>   document (attached) to review the best practices you can incorporate
>   to ensure you are maximizing the possibility of Advertisers desiring
>   to reach your application audience.

I also found that when I was getting the error, I was using the wrong width and height for the control, and fixing that got the ads to appear.